# Does DFSR service exclusively lock files?

Tags: windows-server-2012, dfs-r

I am getting intermittent errors in a single threaded application that writes a large file on a share that is replicated by DFSR.  The error is:

The process cannot access the file '\xxxxx\xxxx\xxx\xx\xxx.xxx'  because it is being used by another process.

I suspect that this is due to DFSR attempting to replicate the file while my application tries to write it.  Is this a known issue?  How can I "prove" this is the cause?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Process Explorer or handles.exe from Sysinternals and searching for the file name to see what process on the system has an open handle to the file?

If dfsrs.exe has an open handle to the file when the error occurs, then I guess you have your culprit.